# Duplicate a layer in google Autodraw

Tags: icons, drawing, layer

I want to duplicate a icon in google's [Autodraw](https://www.autodraw.com/). Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use copy/paste keyboard shortcuts when the icon is selected.

On Mac: Command-C, Command-V
On Windows: Control-C, Control-V

Voila:
[image: example copied icons]